# How can I add values to a specific column of an excel file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a List of Maps like:

```
[
{Er_NO=123, ER_Name=ABC, ER_Code=A01}, 
{Er_NO=789, ER_Name=GHI, ER_Code=C01}, 
{Er_NO=456, ER_Name=DEF, ER_Code=B01}
]
```

Now I need to insert these values in a new Excel file based on a specific column. 
Lets say, the mapping is something like:

```
Er_NO : C
ER_Name : E
ER_Code : G
```

where C, E and G are the columns in the excel file.

I know how to add the values row-wise by creating new rows and keep adding the values using POI but I am not sure how to add the values in specific columns. Can somebody plz help?

Comment: if you can package your data in a text file, you can use a **VBA** macro to read and parse the data and populate Excel columns.

Comment: I am afraid if I can include VB in my Java project :-)
Is there any solution possible in Java?

Comment: I don't know..................................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

specified the column using column id

```
XSSFCell cell = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(0); // 0 = id of the 1th row, 0 = id of the 1st (A) column
```

specified the column using column name

```
XSSFCell cell = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(CellReference.convertColStringToIndex("A"));
```

then add value into the desired cell